# Executing program gives int cannot be converted into java.lang.string

Tags: java, oop, bluej

I am currently using BlueJ (forced to by the module tutor, I hate it) and I'm having an error come up every time I attempt to execute the code.

> incompatible types: java.lang.String cannot be converted into int

My code is as follows:

```
public class middle 
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    String numeroUno = args[0];
    String numeroDos = args[1];
    String numeroTres = args[2];

    double num1 = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
    double num2 = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
    double num3 = Double.parseDouble(args[2]);

    middle(num1, num2, num3);
}

public static void middle(double n1, double n2, double n3)
{
    double [] values = {n1, n2, n3};
    double newarr;
    boolean sorted = false;

    while(!sorted)
    {
        sorted = true;
        for(int i=0; i<values.length-1; i++)
        {
            if(values[i] > values[i+1])
            {
                double swapsies = values[i+1];
                values[i+1] = values[i];
                values[i] = swapsies;
                sorted = false;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.print(values[1] + " is between " + values[0] + " and " + values[2]);

}
}
```

Firstly my question is where have I made the error, but secondly, is there another way to structure this code i.e completely rewrite it to achieve the same thing. I'm not really used to writing code this way and I'm having a hard time with OOP. The object of this particular exercise is to write code that will return the middle value number from what the user has input.

Thanks!

Comment: there should be a linenumber alongside the error-message... And for me that code works just fine.

Comment: No, that's why I say I'm having a hard time with BlueJl. It just says Error: incompatible types. There is no mention of a line number or any fragments of code.

Comment: With what parameters did you launch it / what were the exact values you entered into the parameter-fields? If I remember correctly, you had to use double quotes for string-parameters. Might be that the input-format simply wasnt correct

Comment: I dont know about BlueJ so this is just a guess, is it maybe that your program simply has to return the NUMBER i.e. 5, and not a whole string to successfully pass the BlueJ exercise? (just guessing from experience I had while learning at my school)

Comment: bro the code works better shift to net beans and dont consider swappings when you got only 3 elements use sort and print middle value

Comment: Ill provide code if u want to have

Comment: Okay @Paul so I'm in the project interface of BlueJ and I right click the class this is written in (no other classes) and click on void main (String[] args). It then gives me a prompt with just `{}` and I enter `3, 4, 5` within those brackets. Then the error comes

Comment: @Akhil I'm pretty sure it should work, but I'm required to use BlueJ by the professor who is teaching the module. I personally would love to use Netbeans or Eclipse but unfortunately I have to use this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BlueJ's parameter-interfaces that are used to call methods or constructors are designed to take arguments in `java`-syntax. So for example the parameter window for `main` would expect input in the form:

```
{"2" , "3" , "4"}
```

Note the double-quotes just like in `java`. In fact this principle is extensible for any kind of constructor. For example one could as well give `{new String("2"), new String("3"), ...` as arguments.

Comment: As a side note, if you were to navigate from the terminal to your BlueJ project, you could run `java middle 2 3 4` and things would work as well. Though @Paul's answer is definitely the BlueJ way to do it.